# How to find the exact table names in the user Query in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL developer I have a Query in which I have to find all the table names which are starting as 'DIM' and 'FCT' and 'ABC'.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM DIM_TABLE,fct_table,abc_table WHERE..
```

I am trying through regular expression instring and substring.But unable to get the exact end position of the table.

Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is as follows:

a. first extract the part of the query that contains table names separated by comma

b. convert comma separated values to rows

c. Filter out the rows by the criteria given

```
select * from( 
            select  trim(regexp_substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR('SELECT * FROM DIM_TABLE,fct_table,abc_table WHERE','FROM (.*) WHERE',1,1,null,1),'[^,]+', 1, level) ) value, level
              from dual
             connect by regexp_substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR('SELECT * FROM DIM_TABLE,fct_table,abc_table WHERE','FROM (.*) WHERE',1,1,null,1), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
               )
        where 
        value like 'DIM%' or value like 'fct%' or value like 'abc%'
```

**results:**

```
DIM_TABLE
fct_table
abc_table
```

**EDIT 2:** 
ok 
So now that you have changed your original query this will look like the following:

```
select * from( 
select  trim(regexp_substr(
replace (
replace (
replace (
REGEXP_SUBSTR('SELECT * FROM DIM_TABLE INNER JOIN FCT_TABLE ON FCT_TABLE.COL1 = DIM_TABLE.COL1 LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC_TABLE WHERE','FROM (.*) WHERE',1,1,null,1),
 'INNER JOIN',',') ,'LEFT OUTER JOIN',','), 'ON',',XXX')
 ,'[^,]+', 1, level) ) value, level
  from dual
 connect by regexp_substr(
   replace (
replace (
replace (
REGEXP_SUBSTR('SELECT * FROM DIM_TABLE INNER JOIN FCT_TABLE ON FCT_TABLE.COL1 = DIM_TABLE.COL1 LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC_TABLE WHERE','FROM (.*) WHERE',1,1,null,1),
 'INNER JOIN',',') ,'LEFT OUTER JOIN',','), 'ON',',XXX')
   , '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
   )
where 
value like 'DIM%' or value like 'FCT%' or value like 'ABC%'
```

**Results 2**

```
DIM_TABLE   1
FCT_TABLE   2
ABC_TABLE   4
```

It is not pretty - but it works - I think you got the idea...

Comment: Thanks for replying...its working...but again am struck when there is a slight change in query like;  Query: SELECT * FROM DIM_TABLE INNER JOIN FCT_TABLE ON FCT_TABLE.COL1 = DIM_TABLE.COL1 LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC_TABLE WHERE

Comment: @anandbaskar take a look at my second version... of course you would do as many `replaces` as needed to cover all your different cases...

Comment: yes i got the idea...thank you...Can you just give me a short info about level and connect by...what it exactly do generally

Comment: @anandbaskar You're welcome.  May be this link will help [question-about-connect-by-level](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=question-about-connect-by-level). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT table_name
      FROM user_tables 
      WHERE table_name like 'DIM%'
           OR table_name like 'FCT%'
           OR table_name like 'ABC%'
```

Comment: Thanks for replying...but i need those tables which are present in the query.Not all the tables